# Python class member behaving as if it's static?

Tags: python, list

I'm writing my first python program and I'm running into something that seems strange.

My program looks like this:

```
def main():
  listOfThings = []
  for i in range(0,3):
    newThing = thing()
    newThing.listOfStrings.append('newString')
    listOfThings.append(newThing)
```

Thing simply looks like this:

```
class thing:
  listOfStrings = []
```

I'm expecting listOfThings to be:

```
listOfThings
 -thing1
  -newString
 -thing2
  -newString
 -thing3
  -newString
```

But instead i'm getting this:

```
listOfThings
 -thing1
  -newString
  -newString
  -newString
 -thing2
  -newString
  -newString
  -newString
 -thing3
  -newString
  -newString
  -newString
```

In other languages, this is what I would expect to see if thing.listOfStrings was static. Is there some subtlety of python that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`listOfStrings` is a class attribute. All the instances will share the same `list`

Instead you should add the attribute during `__init__`

```
class thing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listOfStrings = []
```

Comment: So how do I create an object with it's own list?

Comment: Same way you've been doing it, `thing()`.

Comment: @Justin984, `thing()` just as you were doing. `__init__` is called automatically when you create the instance

Comment: This only works because `list` is a mutable type. If `listOfThings` was a `str` (immutable and therefore not modifiable in-place), the results would vary

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks a lot! So is this always the way to do instance variables vs class variables?

Answer (score 4):

In Python, any "variables" declared at class scope become *class attributes*, which are akin to static class members in other languages. They can be accessed either through the class name `thing.listOfStrings` or an instance `newThing.listOfStrings`, but they always refer to the same attribute.

If you want *instance attributes*, create them in an `__init__` method:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listOfStrings = []
```

Every time you instantiate a new instance of `Thing` using `Thing()`, the `__init__` will run in the new instance and give it its own `listOfStrings` list.

Note that due to Python's dynamic nature, `__init__` is not the only place where instance attributes can be added (though it is the recommended location). For example, the following is legal:

```
class Foo:
    pass # empty class definition

a = Foo()
a.x = 42
print a.x # prints 42

b = Foo()
b.y = 99
print b.x # raises AttributeError
print b.y # prints 99
```